# Magento 2.2.3: Merging error in data migration tool

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

Acutally, We migrated our data once but now most of development has done. So, i need to merge new data in existing database. I fired migrate:delta command but gives error: Deltalog for customer_entity is not installed

[image]

please help to resolve this error...

Answer (score 0):

Did you migrate settings or data before migrate delta?

I am currently in the same process as you, that mistake I made yesterday also to me when doing a migrate data before doing a migrate delta. What I did was go back to a previous backup of the database and then do a delta migration.

Now the problem that I have Mismatch of entities in the document  can be seen in the page of the data migration tool https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/539

So I would start by going back to a previous Magento 2 backup and then doing a Delta from the Magento 1 Database.

Comment: Yes, I have migrated settings and data before migrate delta.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your migration tool is outdated?

```
https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/347
https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/306
```

**Possible fix**:

https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/pull/344/commits/2393847bb4ed2a5f4f12d1c28e42e78d29a279a2

Comment: yes,  i didn't updated it from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3, I will try after updating it.